# How to use variables in __asm?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm compiling this C++ code with the VC compiler. I'm trying to call a function that takes two `WORD` (aka `unsigned short`) parameters using the `__asm` statement, like this:

```
__declspec(naked) void __stdcall CallFunction(WORD a, WORD b)
{
    __asm {
        PUSH EBP
        MOV EBP, ESP
        PUSH a
        PUSH b
        CALL functionAddress
        LEAVE
        RETN
    }
}
```

The function at `functionAddress` simply outputs the result of doing `a + b`. Then calling `CallFuncion(5, 5);` prints "64351" or something like that. The problem is when using the `a` and `b` variables inside the `__asm` statement because this works:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
PUSH 5
PUSH 5
CALL functionAddress
LEAVE
```

This is the function at `functionAddress`:

```
void __stdcall Add(WORD a, WORD b)
{
    WORD c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("The result is %d\n", c);
}
```

How can I do this the right way? So the `__asm` statement interpretate the `a` and `b` values?

Comment: "the VC compiler" there have been many versions. Please be more verbose and specific about your environment.

Comment: You're saying it calls `CallFunction` again, that's infinite recursion, please be more clear.

Comment: It's the VC 2005 compiler if I'm not wrong. @user9000 Sorry, I call the function later outside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `__declspec(naked)` and setting up your own stack frame, I don't believe the compiler will let you refer to `a` and `b` by name. Using `__declspec(naked)` basically means you're responsible for dealing with the stack frame, parameters, etc., on your own.

You probably want code more on this general order:

```
__asm {
    PUSH EBP
    MOV EBP, ESP 
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    push eax
    push ebx
    CALL functionAddress
    LEAVE
    RETN
}
```

I'ts been a while since I've handled things like this by hand, so you might want to re-check those offsets, but if I recall correctly, the return address should be at `[ebp+4]`. Parameters are (usually) pushed from right to left, so the the left-most parameter should be  next at `[ebp+8]`, and the next parameter at `[ebp+12]` (keeping in mind that the stack grows downward).

Edit: [I should have looked more carefully at the function heading.]

You've marked `CallFunction` as using the `__stdcall` calling convention. That means it's required to clean up the parameters that were passed to it. So, since it receives 8 bytes of parameters, it needs to remove 8 bytes from the stack as it returns:

```
    PUSH EBP
    MOV EBP, ESP
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    push eax
    push ebx
    CALL Add_f
    LEAVE
    RET 8
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I'm very new to ASM. Sorry, but there's a little problem: after the function is called I'm getting an `Access violation while reading 00000005` and OllyDbg remarks the `LEAVE` instruction. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: The statement in the first paragraph is incorrect -- x86 supports instructions like `push dword ptr [ebp+8]` allowing you to read a value from memory and push it on the stack all at once.  Your asm code clobbers `ebx`, which is normally callee save, so will likely cause problems.  Use `ecx` or `edx` instead.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Are you (perhaps) thinking of another compiler and/or 64-bit code? For 32-bit VC++: [When using __asm to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06.aspx)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer @ChrisDodd but I'm still getting the Access violation when the program ends, using `exc` or `edx`. Any other idea?

Comment: @cdonts: Sounds like a mismatch in calling convention. Are you sure the function you're calling cleans up after itself, or do you need to clear the parameters back off the stack yourself after calling it?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: If you read that link carefully, you'll note that it only applies to `cdecl`/`stdcall` functions and NOT to `declspec(naked)` functions.  In particular, while it will add the save/restore of `ebx` to the prolog/epilog for you, that obviously won't happen if you're not generating a prolog/epilog

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The function is specified as `stdcall`. This isn't about what will be handled in the prolog/epilog. A `stdcall` prolog/epilog don't save/restore ebx. But, the function is *marked* a `stdcall`, which means the compiler doesn't expect it to preserve ebx--if it needs ebx saved, it does so on its own (in the calling code).